# vim cursor keep scrolling after long tap the key 'j'

Tags: vim

As we know in vim, we can long tap on the key 'j', then the cursor would keep on moving down, but when I release the key 'j', it would keep on moving for a while.
how to make it stop immediately when I release the key？

Comment: I don't think you can. vim is reacting to key presses. When you press your key a long time, it is the keyboard driver that starts sending the individual key presses. Vim reacts to them as fast as it can, but sometimes not fast enough. When you stop pressing the key, vim still has some of the presses to process, and that is what it does. Look for "keyboard repeat rate" settings in your OS.

Comment: H, M, L is handy to move within screen.  ^F ^B are good for scrolling pages.

Comment: As @yosukesabai tries to emphasize, holding a cursor movement key is generally a vim anti-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because you fill in this way [the keyboard buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_buffer).